# HTML links just reload the page

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I have the following code:

```
<html><head><title>Top Stories</title></head>
<body><h2>Top Stories</h2><ul>
<li><a href "abc.html">ABC News: Top Stories</a></li>
<li><a href "cbs.html">Breaking News: CBS News</a></li>
<li><a href "cnn.html">CNN.com - Top Stories</a></li>
<li><a href "fox.html">FOXNews.com</a></li>
<li><a href "nbc.html">NBCNews.com: Top NBCNews headlines</a></li>
</ul></body></html>
```

For some reason, I can't seem to get the links to go to their respective pages. The browser says the links point to index.html but that doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Woking Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Bx9f9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set the `href` attribute *equal* to the URL:

```
<li><a href="abc.html">ABC News: Top Stories</a></li>
<li><a href="cbs.html">Breaking News: CBS News</a></li>
<li><a href="cnn.html">CNN.com - Top Stories</a></li>
<li><a href="fox.html">FOXNews.com</a></li>
<li><a href="nbc.html">NBCNews.com: Top NBCNews headlines</a></li>
```

Right now, you just have an `href` attribute with no value, so it defaults to the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's correct.
equals sign was missing in the code.

Please find the href syntax below:

Link text